# How to have a transparent figure with a darkgrid background in seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

The default behavior when saving a transparent image is to set the background to be transparent, but I want the background as is, and the white space surrounding the plot in the figure to be transparent.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# Set background of the charts' to be a dark grid.
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="smoker", col_order=["Yes", "No"])
g = g.map(plt.hist, "total_bill")

# Save figure with a transparent background (but this unfortunately)
# overrides the dark grid, whereas I want the white surrounding the
# plots to be transparent.
plt.savefig("example.pdf", transparent=True)
```

Figure as shown in the notebook (with the darkgrid)
[image: Figure as shown in the notebook (with the darkgrid).]

Figure as it looks saved (no background)
[image: Figure as it looks saved (no background)]

Comment: `facecolor=(1,1,1,0)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is this meant to be added to the `plt.savefig(*)` call? For me, that ends up again with a white background.

Comment: It should replace the `transparent` argument.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me -- I'd mark your comment as "answered my question" if I could.

(I had not cleared the kernel after running the suggestion below which was the problem before).

Comment: This should be the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You can update `matplotlib`'s `rcParams` to make the figure background transparent but keep the grid active, adding this to your code:

```
from matplotlib import rc

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.transparent'] = True
```

Comment: When I add this to my snippet above the darkgrid bleeds out and covers the entire figure -- e.g. there is nothing transparent, there is only the darkgrid background. Does this happen for you as well?